# Sharepoint online -- managed metadata term set filter not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, managed-metadata, term-set, treeview

Novice user here. We have created a list of products on sharepoint online. Products are tagged using a managed metadata term set. We would like to use this to either A) filter the list and save views or B) have the term set displayed in tree view and allow the user to filter the list as they wish. I can not get a tree view to appear (only filter checkboxes like on a choice list), and I can not filter the list if I have more than 16 boxes checked. It is for government intranet use, so it might be that tree view is not an option for us -- site settings "look and feel" does not have "tree view" or "Navigation Elements" listed. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to use Metadata Navigation by products types in the list.

1.Go to site settings -> site administrator -> term store management, then create new group(Metadata Navigation) -> new tern set(products types) -> create new term.

2.Go to your list settings, create a new column called products types by Managed Metadata type, in the Term Set Settings section choose products types, click OK.

3.Populate data in products types column.

4.Go to site settings -> site actions -> manage site features, active Metadata Navigation and Filtering feature.

5.Go to your list settings, click Metadata Navigation settings, Available Hierarchy Fields add products types, Available Key Filter Fields add products types, click Ok.

Comment: Thank you! I've completed these steps. I would like to filter using tree view, and be able to filter using more than 16 terms -- neither of which I can get to work. The former may not be available as it's not listed in the "look and feel" section.